# Find limit of a function (two different calculators give different answers)

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} (\ln(x))^{\tan(x)}$$

Wolframalpha says that limit is 1. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+ln+%28x%29%29%5E+tan+%28x%29+as+x-%3E0

eMathhelp says that 0 is not in the domain of the function: https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/limit-calculator/?f=%28ln%28x%29%29%5Etan%28x%29&var=&val=0&dir=&steps=on

What site is correct and what are the steps to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of the function $$x \mapsto (\ln(x))^{\tan(x)}$$

is $$\{x\in \Bbb R \; : \; ln(x)>0 \wedge x\ne \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\}$$

$$=\{x\in \Bbb R \; : \; x>1 \wedge x\ne \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \}$$
where $ k\in \Bbb N$.
thus this function is not defined near zero.

We cannot speak about its limit when $ x$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Both are right !

The fact is that Alpha computes in $\mathbb C$ and allows logarithms of negatives.

Whereas eMathHelp computes in $\mathbb R$ where the limit does not exist.

---

Alpha computing in the complex is a frequent source of misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

The limit as in $$\lim_{x \to 0} (\ln(x))^{\tan(x)}$$ does not exist because the function is not defined around $x=0$

Comment: If $x$ is positive zero, then $\ln(\ln(x))$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @AndrewFount  Thanks for the informative comment.